# How to show remain item column of an order in shipment pdf?

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, shipment

I am using Megento 1.9.3

I need to add a column "**Remain Item**" in shipment PDF. For your convenient I am sharing a sample image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the pdf you need to overwrite `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment` and `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Shipment_Default`. 
If you already have done that, you just need to change the two methods below and add the header in the first method and the values in the second.
Anyway you need to adjust the column width depending on your layout, just adjust the 'feed' parameter for all your column headers and values to fit in the page.

The value for the left to ship quantity can be taken from the corresponding order item using the method `getQtyToShip()`.

Here is the code you should use. Please adapt the feed parameter as described. The column header I set in my example is 'Items to Ship', Magento's default. Feel free to use your own
value for that:

```
//Overwrite Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment

protected function _drawHeader(Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        /**
         * Draw table header for product items
         *
         * @param  Zend_Pdf_Page $page
         * @return void
         */

        [...]

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'),
            'feed'  => 35
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Items to Ship'),
            'feed'  => 35
        );

        [...]

    }


//Overwrite  Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Shipment_Default

/**
 * Draw item line
 */
public function draw()
{

   [...]

    // draw QTY
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $item->getQty()*1,
        'feed'  => 35
    );

    // draw Qty left to ship
    $lines[0][] = array(
        'text'  => $item->getOrderItem()->getQtyToShip(),
        'feed'  => 35
    );

   [...]
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. It worked fine.

Can you please tell me if I want to show total shipped count column, then how I can do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the order item you have a method `getQtyShipped()`, I guess that's what you need. The remaining qty is the result of qty ordered minus qty shipped, qty canceled and qty refunded.